# Is there a different runtime configuration file for Vim than gVim?

Tags: vim

I have a .vimrc file in my home directory in which I have put some vim commands but those commands only work in gVim and not in Vim. What is the problem? Is there another config file for Vim?

By the way, here is my .vimrc file:

```
  1 colorscheme desert
  2 " To save, ctrl-s.
  3 nmap <c-s> :w<CR>
  4 imap <c-s> <Esc>:w<CR>a
  5 " Set the boolean number option to true
  6 set number
  7 highlight LineNr term=bold cterm=NONE ctermfg=DarkGrey ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE     guifg=DarkGrey guibg=NONE
  8 " Set the shift width(for Python programmnig)"
  9 set sw=4
 10 "Convert all tabs to an equivalent spaces"
 11 set expandtab
 12 set softtabstop=4
 13 retab
 14 "Show cursor position in status bar"
 15 set ruler
```

PS. I only cannot run the command Ctrl-s in the vim and I am able to run other commands in vim as gVim.

Answer (score 4):

http://pangea.stanford.edu/computing/unix/shell/loginstuck.php

`Ctrl-S` in terminal is `XOFF`, so the terminal may be interpreting it and not passing it on to vim.

Try setting a different colorscheme or other visible change to make sure your .vimrc is loaded.

Alternatively, run "`:nmap`" to see what your current normal mode mappings are to confirm you have them.

UPDATE: The fix is to undefine the stop sequence explicitly

```
stty stop undef
```

or to disable XON/XOFF flow control as suggested by @Sam Brinck

```
stty -ixon
```

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely the issue. Is there a way to change this behavior in gnome-terminal?

Comment: add `stty -ixon` to your .bashrc

Comment: According to this link (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/48880), you should be able to set `stty stop undef` in your terminal to disable it.  I confirmed it on my Ubuntu 11.04 box.

Comment: great. with running the command "stty stop undef" in my terminal I become able t use ctrl-s in vim. @nheeshmar could you please include your last comment in your answer? I want to choose it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [.gvimrc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui.html#.gvimrc)

Comment: I don't have problem with my gVim. The problem is that  the vim doesn't use .vimrc .

Comment: Sorry, the title is a bit misleading for me. By the way, if you have a .vimrc in your home dir then vim will use it. Why do you think vim isn't loading .vimrc? What's the issue?

Comment: I cannot run the commands in vim. For example, ctrl-s doesn't work (but it works in gVim).

Comment: This is probably related to gnome-terminal It's not a vim issue. Try to set nonumber and then launch vim. If you don't see number then the problem is not vim related

Comment: Yes, you are right. when I put "set nonumber" the numbers disappeared in vim. So it means there is something wrong with my gnome terminal. what is your guess? thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help. I tried in the past to get <c-s> working but I got tired of searching for a solution. Now I use only gVim...

Comment: I ran into the same problem with <C-s> @bheeshmar's answer was what fixed it for me. if you are using bash add `stty -ixon` to your .bashrc. This will cause gnome-terminal to pass the <C-s> to vim.